# something C# writing multiplying code in static

Tags: c#

first of all, i apologize if this question has already been asked. This is my first time asking something on stackoverflow.

so, i am currently learning C# and decided to write a piece of code for practise.
this monstrocity is the result:

```
static class Calculator
{
    public static int multiply;

    public static int Sum(int times1, int times2)
    {

        multiply= times1 * times2;
        return multiply; 
    }  

    public new static string ToString()
    {
        return $"this is the result of a calculation/multiplication: {multiply}";
    }
}
```

pretty neat right? its supposed to return a simple multiplication and print it in the main string using an override ToString method (but since that cant be done in static, I made a new one and used that).

```
 class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Calculator.ToString());
    }

}
```

this is where the problem comes into play, because the console simply states:

> this is the result of a calculation/multiplication: 0

even when i assign values to 'times1' and 'times2' the result is the same.
I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here, can anybody help me out?

Comment: You never called `Sum`, so `multiply` still holds its original value - 0

Comment: Your program isn't calling `Sum()` anywhere.

Comment: i see, i'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply doesn't contain a value. First call Sum function with whatever numbers you want to multiply and then you can write the result.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Calculator.Sum(2, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(Calculator.ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's due to the static keyword. So, basically, your new static method ToString()(is not the best name) knows nothing about multiply returned after Sum execution,

1. Do not use static at all
2. Perform calculation directly in ToString()(suggest to rename =))